# Part of custom view not rendering at runtime?

Tags: android

I've written a custom view that generate a Google Map Marker at runtime, code below:

```
public class CustomMapMarker extends View {

    Paint paint;
    Path bodyPath;
    Path dotPath;
    private Paint paint2;
    private int backGroundColor;
    private int foreGroundColor;
    Matrix scaleMatrix;

    public CustomMapMarker(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        init(context);

    }

    public CustomMapMarker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomMapMarker);
        try {
            backGroundColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.CustomMapMarker_markerBackgroundColor, Color.parseColor("#4180e0"));
            foreGroundColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.CustomMapMarker_dotBackgroundColor, Color.WHITE);
        }
        finally {
            a.recycle();
        }
        init(context);

    }

    public CustomMapMarker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
        bodyPath = new Path();
        dotPath = new Path();

        paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(backGroundColor);

        paint2 = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint2.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint2.setColor(foreGroundColor);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {


        bodyPath.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);

        bodyPath.moveTo(132, 416);
        bodyPath.cubicTo(123, 370, 107, 332, 87, 297);
        bodyPath.cubicTo(72, 270, 55, 246, 39, 221);
        bodyPath.cubicTo(33, 212, 29, 203, 24, 194);
        bodyPath.cubicTo(14,177,5,156, 6, 130);
        bodyPath.cubicTo(6,104,14,83,25,66);
        bodyPath.cubicTo(42,38,72,15,112,9);
        bodyPath.cubicTo(145, 4, 176,12,197,25);
        bodyPath.cubicTo(215, 36, 229,49,239,66);
        bodyPath.cubicTo(250, 83, 258, 103,258,129);
        bodyPath.cubicTo(259, 143, 256, 155, 253, 166);
        bodyPath.cubicTo(250, 176, 245, 185, 241, 194);
        bodyPath.cubicTo(232, 212, 221, 229, 210, 246);
        bodyPath.cubicTo(177, 296, 146, 347, 132, 416);


        bodyPath.close();

        dotPath.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);
        dotPath.arcTo(82, 85, 182, 185, 270, 360, true);
        dotPath.close();

        bodyPath.addPath(dotPath);

        RectF drawableRect = new RectF(0, 0, 265, 412);
        RectF viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        scaleMatrix.setRectToRect(drawableRect, viewRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
        bodyPath.transform(scaleMatrix);
        dotPath.transform(scaleMatrix);

        canvas.drawPath(bodyPath, paint);
        canvas.drawPath(dotPath, paint2);

    }


    public void setBackgroundColor(int mColor) {
        this.backGroundColor = mColor;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    public void setForeGroundColor(int mColor) {
        this.foreGroundColor = mColor;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        int desiredWidth = 255;
        int desiredHeight = 412;

        int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
        int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
        int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

        int width;
        int height;

        if (widthMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            width = widthSize;
        } else if (widthMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
            width = Math.min(desiredWidth, widthSize);
        } else {
            width = desiredWidth;
        }

        if (heightMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            height = heightSize;
        } else if (heightMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
            height = Math.min(desiredHeight, heightSize);
        } else {
            height = desiredHeight;
        }

        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }


}
```

Which in the XML preview, displays as intended:

[image]

However, at runtime, embedding this marker somewhere in the app to test with, the white dot is not visible?

[image]

Would anyone with more experience with custom views be able to shed some light on this? I presume it's something to do with the way i'm scaling the path to make it fit any size?

Comment: Don't use hardcoded numbers, calculate the path with getWidth() and getHeight() and percentages of those,, then you don't need the scaling at all. Why add dotpath to bodypath? In your setXXXColor functions you have to use paint.setColor(), or they will have no effect.

Comment: @ElDuderino Thanks for the response, good call on the setXXXColors, they aren't actually used right now but would have stung me later! Unfortunately, regarding scaling i am very much inexperienced with programtic drawing and/or custom views and would have very little success attempting the proper method you mentioned!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found some time to look at your problem.

1) Use addArc() instead of arcTo(). If all you want is a circle, don't use a path, use canvas.drawCircle(). I'd do that.

2) Do not create objects in onDraw(). Use onSizeChanged() to create your pathes, that's the time when you know how big your view is. You can then calculate your path depending on width and height of your view. Thus you don't need to scale anything. In onDraw() you just draw.

```
@Override
public void onSizeChanged(int width, int height, int oldWidth, int oldHeight) {
    bodyPath = getBodyPath(width, height);
    dotPath = getDotPath(width, height);
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    canvas.save();
    if(bodyPath != null) {
        canvas.drawPath(bodyPath, backgroundPaint);
    }

    if(dotPath != null) {
        canvas.drawPath(dotPath, foregroundPaint);
    }

    //or just a circle
    //canvas.drawCircle(getWidth()/2, getHeight()/3,Math.min(getWidth(),getHeight())/5,foregroundPaint);

    canvas.restore();
}
```

getBodyPath() e.g. looks like this

```
private Path getOutlinePath(float w, float h) {
    Path bodyPath = new Path();
    bodyPath.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);
    bodyPath.moveTo(w* 0.5f, h);
    bodyPath.cubicTo(w * 0.4f, h * 0.8f, w * 0.3f, h * 0.7f, w * 0.25f, h * 0.6f);
    bodyPath.cubicTo(w * 0.2f, h * 0.5f, w * 0.1f, h * 0.5f, 0, h * 0.3f);
    bodyPath.cubicTo(0, h * 0.25f, w * 0.25f, 0, w * 0.5f, 0);
    bodyPath.cubicTo(w * 0.75f, 0, w, h * 0.25f, w, h * 0.5f);
    bodyPath.close();
    return bodyPath;
}
```

Yes it is an ugly path, but you can see how I use the width and height of the view to calculate the control points. That way you don't need your scale matrix and you don't need onMeasure(). The path will fit any size.